# Can't access tomcat over network

Tags: tomcat

I cannot access Tomact 7 from a client machine over my local network, the browser times out. On the server, I am able to access Tomcat via localhost or the ip address.

I've been informed there are no firewall restrictions on the network.

**What I've tried**

**A.)** I've added a second host with the ip address as the name

Tomcat server.xml

```
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
    ...

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
      ...

      </Host>

      <Host name="10.x.x.x"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
...
      </Host>
```

**B.)** I've added an alias with to the localhost host

Tomcat server.xml
   
        ...

```
      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
      ...
      <Alias>10.x.x.x</Alias>
      </Host>
```

**C.)** I've tried setting address on the connector to 0.0.0.0 with the added host and with only the localhost host and an alias inside it.

Comment: whats the url you are trying? also did you check what port the service provider has open?

Comment: http://10.x.x.x:8081

Comment: normally port 8080 is used.

Comment: I've configured it to run on 8081

Comment: well that is crucial, did you try to run on port 8080 and see what happens?

Comment: I have another service occupying port 8080. From the server, I am able to launch Tomcat via 10.x.x.x:8081 and localhost:8081

Comment: port 80 or 8080? What service would that be as well?

Comment: 80 was a typo; corrected it. Another service is on port 8080.

Comment: hmmm maybe that service is interfering also, or sometimes service providers block ports.

Comment: Can't fathom how a service running on 8080 would prevent access over the network to one on 8081. IT confirms there are no firewall restrictions.

Comment: well maybe they are colliding some how when you try to access from another computer you never know and yes none from the IT but maybe the ISP has a port blocked for a reason. Since 8080 can be used for a DoS attack

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I'm not access this over the internet. I'm access it from a client on the same network via private IP so even if the ISP were blocking port 8081 that wouldn't be an issue here.

Comment: Then it is most definitely a firewall issue, linux or windows server?

Comment: It's a Windows server

Comment: run `netsh firewall set opmode mode = disable` as an admin then try again